# What does phrasal verb buy in mean?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Today during preparing to PMI-ACP exam I bumped into phrase "buy in".

All dictionaries explain the meaning of this phrasal verb as "To buy something in large quantity". Is there any other meanings? Because in context that I have heard it, has no sense to me.

The whole sentence "Develop team rules and processes to foster buy in".

Comment: Hello, Ivan. This is the compound noun _buy-in_. Look it up in a dictionary. // 'Buy in', a multi-word verb, has the more basic sense 'buy a lot of something [often in the past from a general store]' at least in British English  (see M-W), but the business and 'get on board' senses now predominate. The compound noun for the basic sense was _buying in_ as in 'I haven't done this week's buying in yet'.

Comment: Yep, "buy in" (or "buy-in") is usually used as a noun, not a verb.  As a verb it would generally be read as the plain, vanilla "buy" followed by the plain, vanilla preposition "in".

Comment: Google it. Good Luck.

Comment: How funny, I never heard the BrE usage of "this week's buying in". Good to know. This dumb corporate tendency (mostly American, of course) of using these stupid sounding jargon words can drive one batty.

Comment: I can't find the original anywhere, Ivan. Can you provide a link, please? It sounds rather like a to-less to-infinitive clause rather than a sentence, and seems to use headlinese.

Comment: My experience with the phrase "buy in" always involved **belief**. *I don't buy in to that." means: I don't believe that. (American English idiom). I've heard it used that way, since the mid-1960s.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry unfortunately can't provide a link. It's video course on udemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**buy in** [TFD - idiom of buy](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buy+in) an buy into  [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/buy-into)

> 2. To believe in and support an idea, concept, or system.

As in:

> 2. "Rod's a good enough coach, but he just can't get the players to **buy in** — they still don't listen to him." "We can't approach the CEO with our idea for overhauling the computer system until we get our boss to **buy in** first".

And as in: [Rachel's English](http://rachelsenglish.com/phrasal-verb-buy/)

> If you *buy into* something, you believe it.  I bought into the idea
>   that he was going to be a great president.  Or, if someone’s telling
>   you something and it doesn’t seem truthful, you can say, “I don’t buy
>   it.”  That’s like saying, “I don’t believe you.”

Comment: 'Foster' doesn't catenate with infinitives. 'Buy in' can't be a verb here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth these are from the dictionary - I edited to make sure verbatim. Let me know ... i defer to wisdom!

Comment: The verbs in OP's sentence are "develop" and "foster"; "buy in" is a noun.

Comment: I too would like to see the original.

Comment: @lbf You can see the sentence (well, more like sentence fragment) right in the question: "Develop team rules and processes to foster buy in"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - shall i take down my answer?

Comment: Unless OP clarifies and adds research,  I think the whole question should be closed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth aye aye

Comment: def some differences on the sides of the pond